# Get MultiChosen select value on form submit using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, form-submit, jquery-chosen

I am using Chosen Jquery Plugin for populating my select boxes.

I am trying to submit form using jquery and I have to **check the select box whether it has value or not .**

**HTML**

```
<form class="addData" action="getData.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select data-placeholder="Choose a manager.." name="user[]" class="form-control chosen-select" id="user" multiple>
         <option value="7">User1</option>
         <option value="8">User2</option>
         <option value="9">User3</option>
         <option value="10">User4</option>
         <option value="11">User5</option>
         <option value="12">User6</option>
         <option value="13">User7</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#user').chosen({
            width:'100%' ;
         });
         $('.addData').submit(function(){
            var select_val = $('#user').val();
            // var select_val = $('#user').chosen().val();
            if(select_val == "") {
                alert("No data select");
            } else {
                alert("Form is ready to submit");
            }
            return false;
         });
    });
</script>
```

If I have not selected a value `console.log(select_val)` return `null` and 
If I have selected a value `console.log(select_val)` return `Array [ "8", "9" ]` But When i validate it and check like

`if(select_val == "" || select_val == NULL)` it gives me error **ReferenceError: NULL is not defined**

`if(select_val.length == 0)` it gives me error **TypeError: select_val is null**

Please Help me how to validate this variable

Comment: when you are posting the questions you should response those who are answering for you? @Nidhi

Comment: Yeah..Stranger.. Actually, I am busy to finding a solution...@lalithkumar

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
var selected_val = new Array; 
$('#user option:selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
  selected_val[i] = $(selected).val(); 
});
```

Then

```
if(selected_val.length > 0){
    alert("Form is ready to submit");
}
else{
    alert("No data select");
}
```

Comment: did you check like this ? @Nidhi

Comment: I already get data in a variable and my original form contains 7 select boxes so just for only checking any option is select or not, I have to define 7 arrays?